# textBox and if Statement

Tags: c#

I'm trying to have a few textBox's in a Windows Form have data put into a list box.

I only want SOME things in the list box. So what I need to know is:

How can I make an if statement for the textBox?

---

E.G: If textBox2 says "N/A" output " "

E.G: If textBox2 says "25" output "25 years old"

**EDIT:**

Another question: I would I say, IF textbox3 contain "ANYTHING HERE" output ANYTHING + " message" 
?

Comment: by "output" do you mean "add this text as a ListBox item"?

Answer (score 3):

```
if (textBox2.Text == "N/A")
    listBox2.Items.Add("");
else if (textBox2.Text == "25")
    listBox2.Items.Add("25 years old");
```

Comment: the only thing I would change is this: "" => string.Empty

Answer (score 0):

Something like this?

```
if(textBox1.Text == "N/A")
{
    listBox1.Items.Add("");
}
if(textBox1.Text == "25")
{
    listBox1.Items.Add("25 years old");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

On the most basic level this would be:

```
if(textbox2.Text == "N/A")
    listbox.Items.Add(" ");
```

But this approach is absurdly brittle and I'd urge you to dig a little deeper into the requirements to find something a bit more substantial to test on.  I'd be happy to help you hammer this out if you'd provide more detail as to your problem in the question or in comments.

Answer (score 0):

```
if( string.Compare(textBox1.Text, @"N/S") == 0)
{
    listBox.Add(string.Empty);
}   
else if( string.Compare(textBox1.Text, "25") == 0)
{
    listBox.Add("25 years old");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can simply use the *TextChanged* event and put your if there:

```
private void Initialize()
{
  textBox1.TextChanged += new EventHandler(m_textBox1_TextChanged);
}

void m_textBox1_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
  if (textBox1.Text == "N/A")
    ...
  else
    ...
}
```